# Math.max seems to be returning the wrong answer

Tags: java, math, max

I have a list of double values that I don't know the range of and I want to find the maximum value. However, the Math.max function is giving a curious result for this sample code:

```
double a = -100.0;
double maxA = Double.MIN_VALUE;
maxA = Math.max(maxA, a);
System.out.println(maxA);
```

And the output is:

```
4.9E-324
```

So for some reason, Double.MIN_VALUE is being considered the max when compared to -100.0.

Why?

Comment: Thank you for the answers! What I need is double maxA = -Double.MAX_VALUE;

Comment: You need Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY .

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[MIN_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) is:

> A constant holding the smallest positive nonzero value of type double, 2^(-1074).

Not the *most negative* possible value.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks! I didn't even notice it was the smallest positive nonzero value. I just assumed it would actually be the smallest negative value.

Comment: The problem with this definition is that it is inconsistent with the integer types, where MIN_VALUE is indeed the smallest possible value.

Answer (score 0):

**Its pretty obvious -100 is less than 4.9E-324**

```
-100 , -99 ..... -1 , 0 , 4.9E-324 , 1 , 2 , 3......
```

Comment: Only if you know scientific notation.

Answer (score 0):

MIN_VALUE A constant holding the smallest positive nonzero value of type double.

Note "positive" value.

You are comparing it with a negative value is 1 > -1.